# Communication systems normal AM modulation

Tags: computer-engineering, communication

AM transmitter develops a power output of (110 W) across a (70 52) resistive load when a sinusoidal test tone with a peak amplitude of (4 V) is applied to the input of the modulator it is found that the power output increases by 50% of unmodulated power output under these conditions determine:

1. The average power output in each sideband.
2. Modulation index
3. The peak amplitude of the modulated waveform 4- The total average power in the output if the amplitude of the modulating sinusoid is reduced to 3 V.

**Can anyone solve this question please?**

Comment: This looks like homework. We might help with looking at your efforts.

Comment: @SolarMike  actually  it is midterm question  how can u help me ?

Comment: Show your work and explain where you are stuck. Otherwise your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: What is *a (70 52) resistive load*?